# Will compiler ignore inline qualifier for my function?

Tags: c++, inline

I read that having more than a line in a function will falsify "inline", if so how do i get to know when my function is inlined and vice-versa :/

```
inline int foo(int x, int y)
{
   cout<<"foo-boo";
   return (x > y)? x : y;
}
```

Comment: `inline` stopped to be a compiler hint a long time ago. That is, the compiler won't care about `inline`. Who cares however is the linker.

Comment: @0x3l337 where did you read that? [This MSVC page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw1hbe6y.aspx) about `inline` could be useful.

Comment: @101010: That's wrong. It very well has impact on how the compiler treats it. Especially in conjunction with `extern`. It also still is used as a more hint by some compilers to inline the function, even if it is above the thresold it woulöd be automatically inlined.

Comment: @WeatherVane [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_inline_functions.htm)

Comment: @Olaf I'm quite sure that all modern compilers vendors don't consider `inline` as hint anymore.

Comment: @101010 so inline is outdated is that ?

Comment: @0x3l337 it says "The compiler ***can*** ignore the inline qualifier in case defined function is more than a line." (my emphasis).

Comment: @WeatherVane gotcha!

Comment: @0x3l337 I'm afraid so.

Comment: @101010: So, how do you generate actual (callable) code for an `inline` function? You think about `static inline`, but without `static`, i.e. with external linkage, you will run into trouble. `inline` very well has special semantics the compiler has to deal with, much like `register`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inline` is **in no way** related to the number of lines in a function<sup>1</sup>. It is just a compiler **hint**, which the compiler is **not**, by any means, obliged to follow. Whether a function is really inlined when declared `inline`, is implementation-defined.
From C++14 standard draft N3690, §7.1.2:

> A function declaration (8.3.5, 9.3, 11.3) with an `inline` specifier
>   declares an inline function. The `inline` specifier indicates to the
>   implementation that inline substitution of the function body at the
>   point of call is to be preferred to the usual function call mechanism.
>   **An implementation is not required to perform this inline substitution at the point of call** [...]

<sub>(Formatting mine.)</sub>

There are compiler-specific options and attributes to enable/disable inlining for all functions and do other, related stuff. Look up your compiler's documentation for further information.

---

<sup>1</sup> A compiler could take the line count of a function into account when deciding on whether to inline a function or not but that's implementation-defined and not required by the standard.

Answer (score 11):

Remember, inlining is only a request to the compiler, not a command. Compiler can ignore the request for inlining. Compiler may not perform inlining in such circumstances like:

1. If a function contains a loop. (for, while, do-while)
2. If a function contains static variables.
3. If a function is recursive.
4. If a function return type is other than void, and the return statement doesn’t exist in function body.
5. If a function contains switch or goto statement.

Comment: Good answer. Maybe you could format it a bit to make it more readable. Thanks.